# Image in pseudoclass before on github pages

Tags: css, github, github-pages, pseudo-class

Put png in content in pseudoclass ::before.
Tryed every path, GitHub pages wont show it.

https://github.com/tacticSugar/Resume - Repo
https://tacticsugar.github.io/Resume/ - Page

```
.work h3 {
  padding-left: 5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.work h3::before {
  content: url(https://tacticsugar.github.io/Resume/arrow.png);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  transform: scale(.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.5rem;
 }
```

Comment: It works for me in a simple test with basic HTML. Could you show us a complete example including the HTML which definitely show it not working.

Comment: @AHaworth Does it work as rendered by GitHub Pages though? Because that is the specific context of this question. I am sure it works locally in a simple `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

It should work **in the context of GitHub Pages**, since [`rosmeltd/css_pseudoclases`](https://github.com/rosmeltd/css_pseudoclases) does use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) in his GitHub pages site [`rosmeltd.github.io/css_pseudoclases`](https://rosmeltd.github.io/css_pseudoclases/), with the CSS:

```css
/* ============ CHALLENGE 7 ============ */
.challenge--7 .challenge__code p::before,
.challenge--7 .challenge__code p::after {
  content: url(img/smiley.gif);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

For:

```html
<section class="challenge challenge--7">
  <h4 class="challenge__title">
    <b>VII.</b> Inserte la imagen "smiley.gif" antes y después de cualquier elemento &lt;p&gt;, utilizando los pseudoelementos ::before y ::after.
  </h4>
  <div class="challenge__code">
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

In your case [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/) mentions:

> ### [Disallow qualified headings](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-qualified-headings)
>
> Heading (`h3`) should not be qualified.
>
> ```
> .work h3::before {
> ```

For testing, try `h3::before` instead of `.work h3::before`.